# "Object of class Accounts could not be converted to string" in Yii dropDownList

Tags: yii

similarly I have 2 tables in database,accounts and banks,and One to Many Relation between them.
`'banks' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Banks', 'banks_id'),` in Accounts model.

I need to use `Chtml::dropDownList` in account creation form,so I edit `_form.php` to it:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'banks_id'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList($model, 'banks_id', CHtml::listData(Banks::getBanksList(), 'id', 'title','country')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'banks_id'); ?>
</div>
```

and also in Banks model develop `getBanksList by:

```
    public static function getBanksList()
    {
        $userLanguage = Yii::app()->user->getState('lang');
        $result     = array();
        $banks      = self::model()->findAll();

        foreach ($banks as $bank){
            array_push($result, array(
                'id'        =>  $bank->id,
                'title'     =>  ($userLanguage == $bank->default_lang)?$bank->default_name:$bank->en_name,
                'country'   =>  Yii::t('countries',$bank->country),
            ));
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

but it raise `Object of class Accounts could not be converted to string` error ,and in trace it occured at

```
 public static function getIdByName($name)
     {
         return str_replace(array('[]', '][', '[', ']', ' '), array('', '_', '_', '', '_'), $name);
     }
```

in Chtml.php file.where is the problem?I searched a lot,but I couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood where is my problem,I should use `$form` instead of `Chtml`.